# Shifting Columns in SQL Server based on condition

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a column(say col A) which has boolean value, now depending on whether Col A has 0 or 1, I have to write value of another column(say Col B) to two different columns.

(For instance, if Col A has 0, the value of column B has to be written in Column C and column D has to blank and if it has 1, the value of column B has to be written in Column D and column C has to be blank).

Is it even possible to include in a query?
Or I have to import query result in a file and run a script on it?

Comment: Add some sample input and desire output

Comment: Try to provide a clearer example with possible scenarios and expected outcomes, along with what you've tried.

Comment: so this is an insert? update? select?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update with case statements:

```
UPDATE yourtable SET
  col_c = CASE 
          WHEN col_a = 0 THEN col_b 
          WHEN col_a = 1 THEN null
          ELSE col_c END,
  col_d = CASE 
          WHEN col_a = 0 THEN null 
          WHEN col_a = 1 THEN col_b
          ELSE col_d END
```

If col_a is a boolean and it may contain null values, then leave column values intact.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a simple `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT  ColA,
        ColB,
        CASE WHEN ColA = 0 THEN ColB END ColC,
        CASE WHEN ColA = 1 THEN ColB END ColD
FROM dbo.YourTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **Case Statement:**

```
SELECT
    ColA,
    ColB,
    CASE ColA 
        WHEN 0 THEN ColB
        ELSE '' 
    END AS Colc,
    CASE ColA 
        WHEN 0 THEN ''
        ELSE ColB 
    END AS ColD
From TableName
```

Answer (score 0):

CASE statement with all possible values.

```
declare @tab table
(
colA bit,
colB char(2)
)

insert into @tab values (0, 'xx');
insert into @tab values (1, 'yy');
insert into @tab values (null, 'zz');
insert into @tab values (0, null);
insert into @tab values (null, null);

Select colA, colB,
case when colA = 0 then colB end colC,
case when colA = 1 then colB end colD
from @tab
```

OUTPUT:

```
0      xx   xx      NULL
1      yy   NULL    yy
NULL   zz   NULL    NULL
0      NULL NULL    NULL
NULL   NULL NULL    NULL
```